# async task inside click listener passing reference to interface

Tags: android, interface, callback

I currently have a class which implements an interface

this block of code which works, but my task can only be executed once.

```
final ItemShopBuyItemTask buyItemTask = new ItemShopBuyItemTask(getActivity(), this);
            mButtonBuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    buyItemTask.execute(TEXTVIEW_ITEM_NAME);
                }
            });
```

how can I move the `this` inside of the onClick( View v) function when it expects a `itemBoughtTaskListener` which is implemented at the top of the class with: `implements ItemShopBuyItemTask.itemBoughtTaskListener`

```
public ItemShopBuyItemTask(Context context, itemBoughtTaskListener cb){
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mCallback = cb;
    }
```

Comment: what problem getting using current code?

Comment: the task is only able to be called once, when I need it to create the new task on button click, so it can be called multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Fragment is implementing `itemBoughtTaskListener` then need to pass FragmentName.this as second parameter :

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
      ItemShopBuyItemTask buyItemTask = new ItemShopBuyItemTask(getActivity(),
                                                    FragmentClassName.this);
      buyItemTask.execute(TEXTVIEW_ITEM_NAME);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you want this line

```
final ItemShopBuyItemTask buyItemTask = new ItemShopBuyItemTask(getActivity(), this);
```

to be in the onClick method. 
 So you can use

```
final ItemShopBuyItemTask buyItemTask = new ItemShopBuyItemTask(getActivity(), ClassName.class);
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Then what you can do is this:

```
public void accessWebService(){
   ItemShopBuyItemTask buyItemTask = new ItemShopBuyItemTask(getActivity(), itemBoughtTaskListener cb);
   buyItemTask.execute(TEXTVIEW_ITEM_NAME);
}
```

and call this method as many times as you want!!!